# How to Minimize Data Transfer Out From Azure Query in C# .NET

Tags: c#, linq, azure, cloud

I have a small table(23 rows, 2 int columns), just a basic user-activity monitor. The first column represents user id. The second column holds a value that should be unique to every user, but I must alert the users if two values are the same. I'm using an Azure Sql database to hold this table, and Linq to Sql in C# to run the query.

**The problem:** Microsoft will bill me based on data transferred out of their data-centers. I would like have all of my users to be aware of the current state of this table at all times, second by second, and keep data-transfer under 5 GB per month. I'm thinking along the lines of a Linq-To-Sql expression such as

```
UserActivity.Where(x => x.Val == myVal).Count() > 1;
```

But this would download the table to the client, which cannot happen. Should I be implementing a Linq solution? Or would SqlDataReader download less metadata from the server? Am I taking the right approach by using a database at all? Gimme thoughts!

Comment: Is that absolutely 100% sure about `UserActivity.Where(x => x.Val == myVal).Count() > 1;` fetching all the rows from DB? Did you see an actual SQL Query produced by this linq?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, no. Linq queries are rather ambiguous. I've accidentally downloaded the entire contents of a table hundreds of times over rapid fire when I did not understand the implications of casting IQueryable. Suffice it to say, I exercise caution when approaching a Linq solution that involves efficiency.

Comment: Well, you've got your answer. If you just *don't trust* linq in this particular case then use SqlDataReader. That's it. But i would see the actual SQL command first.

Comment: Lets see, it would be something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE HAVING COUNT(MY_COLUMN) > 1`

Comment: GROUP BY MY_COLUMN. Can't forget the GROUP BY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple thoughts here:

First, I strongly encourage you to profile the SQL generated by your LINQ-to-SQL queries. There are several tools available for this, here's one at random (I have no particular preference or affiliation):

[LINQ Profiler from Devart](https://www.devart.com/linqinsight/linq-profiler.html)

Your prior experience with LINQ query inefficiency notwithstanding, the LINQ sample you quote in your question isn't particularly complex so I would expect you could make it or similar work efficiently, given a good feedback mechanism like the tool above or similar.

Second, you don't explicitly mention whether your query client is running in Azure or outside, but I gather from your concern about data egress costs that its running outside Azure. So the data egress costs are going to be query results using the TDS protocol (low-level protocol for SQL Server), which is pretty efficient. Some quick back-of-the-napkin math shows that you should be fine to stay below your monthly 5 GB limit:

- 23 users
- 10 hours/day
- 30 days/month (less if only weekdays)
- 3600 requests/hour/user
- 32 bits of raw data per response

= about 95 MB of raw response data per month

Even if you assume 10x overhead of TDS for header metadata, etc. (and if my math is right :-) ) then you've still got plenty of room underneath 5 GB. The point isn't that you should stop thinking about it and assume it's fine... but don't assume it isn't fine, either. In fact, don't assume anything. Test, and measure, and make an informed choice. I suspect you'll find a way to stay well under 5 GB without much trouble, even with LINQ.

One other thought... perhaps you could consider running your query inside Azure, and weigh the cost of that vs. the cost of data egress under the "query running outside Azure" scenario? This could (for example) take the form of a small Azure Web Job that runs the query every second and notifies the 23 users if the count goes above 1.

[Azure Web Jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

In essence, you wouldn't notify them if the condition is false, only when it's true. As for the notification mechanism, there are various cloud-friendly options:

[Azure mobile push notifications](https://www.devart.com/linqinsight/linq-profiler.html)

[SMS messaging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/twilio-dotnet-how-to-use-for-voice-sms/)

[SignalR notifications](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites)

The key here is to determine whether its more cost-effective and in line with any bigger-picture technology or business goals to have each user issue the query continuously, or to use some separate process in Azure to notify users asynchronously if the "trigger condition" is met.

Best of luck!

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 3):

If it is data transfer you are worried about you need to do your processing on the server and return only the results.  A SQLDataReader solution can return a smaller, already processed set of data to minimise the traffic.

Comment: I'm of the same train of thought. I just have very little experience with data-tier services, so its difficult to decide on the most efficient course of action. This takes on a whole new meaning in cloud computing, when every byte translates to money saved.

Comment: You'll find that data is really quite cheap and you can very easily over optimize and waste a lot of time and money to save a very small amount of money. I'd make sure that you test carefully each option in a small test harness and see how much data is actually generated.  But pre-processing on the server is a good call if the transfered data is causing delays.

Comment: Well, 23 people running this update loop 10 hours a day, expecting second-by-second updates with zero overhead. Pennies can turn into dollars real quick.